# Flutter FutureBuilder shows blank screen

Tags: dart, flutter, snapshot

I am trying to display a list of cartitems in my app with a future builder. 'Awaiting result...' is displayed for maybe 0.5 sec and then only a white screen is shown. When I replace the Listview with a text, the text is shown like intended. So it has something to do with the snapshot I guess...

```
 Widget buildList()  {
return new FutureBuilder<List<CartItem>> (
    future:  getCartItems(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {

 switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
   case ConnectionState.none:
     return new Text('Press button to start');
   case ConnectionState.waiting:
     return new Text('Awaiting result...');
   default:

     print(snapshot.data);
     print(snapshot.hasData);

     return
       (!snapshot.hasData)

           ?
       new Container(
           alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
           child: new CircularProgressIndicator())
           :
       new ListView(
         children: snapshot.data,
       );
 }});
}}
```

This is my **getCartItems**:

```
Future<List<CartItem>> getCartItems() async {
final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

final uid = user.uid;
List<CartItem> cartItems = [];

QuerySnapshot data = await Firestore.instance
    .collection("carts")
    .where('owner', isEqualTo: uid)
    .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments();

data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
  var keys =  doc["products"].keys.toList();
  var values =  doc["products"].values.toList();

   for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
     await Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(keys[i]).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      cartItems.add( new CartItem.fromDocument(ds, values[i]));
      print(cartItems);

     });
  }
});
return cartItems;
 }
```

I know that the Futurebuilder is called twice:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18490

But I don't know how to handle this situation...

Any ideas? Do I really need a FutureBuilder in this scenario?

**EDIT:**

I added some prints in the buildList Widget with following output:

```
Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 5 of 710 libraries in 808ms.
I/flutter (23685): []           <--- snapshit.data
I/flutter (23685): true         <--- snapshot.hasData
```

**EDIT 2:**

Changes, but still not working:

```
    Future<List<CartItem>> getCartItems() async {
   final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

   final uid = user.uid;
   List<CartItem> cartItems = [];

   QuerySnapshot data = await Firestore.instance
       .collection("carts")
       .where('owner', isEqualTo: uid)
       .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
       .getDocuments();

   cartItems = await _fetchDocumentData(data);
   return cartItems;
 }

 Future<List<CartItem>> _fetchDocumentData(data) async {
 List<CartItem> cartItems = [];
 data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
 var keys =  doc["products"].keys.toList();
 var values =  doc["products"].values.toList();
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(keys[i]).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
 cartItems.add( new CartItem.fromDocument(ds, values[i]));
 print(cartItems);
 });
 }
 });
 return cartItems;
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

The output in the console looks like the Futurebuilder is executed before the fetch is completed:

```
I/flutter ( 4535): []          <--- print(snapshot.data) in FutureBuilder
I/flutter ( 4535): true        <--- print(snapshot.hasData) in FutureBuilder
I/flutter ( 4535): [CartItem]  <--- print(cartItems) in _fetchDocumentData
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be here :

```
new ListView(
  children: snapshot.data,
);
```

The parameter `children` takes `List<Widget>` as parameter. You are providing data directly to it as parameter and so it is not showing any results on UI to you.

You can use `ListView.builder` to display your data like this:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        var cartItem = snapshot.data[position];
        return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: Text(cartItem.id)), // just for example
                Expanded(child: Text(cartItem.name)), // just for example
                Expanded(child: Text(cartItem.color)), // just for example
            ],
        );
    },
)
```

**Edit:**
put code to fetch data in a method like `_fetchDocumentData` and declare that method `async` and have return type of `Future<List<CartItem>>` like this:

```
Future<List<CartItem>> _fetchDocumentData async {    
   List<CartItem> cartItems = [];    
   data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
     var keys =  doc["products"].keys.toList();
     var values =  doc["products"].values.toList();

     for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        await Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(keys[i]).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
         cartItems.add( new CartItem.fromDocument(ds, values[i]));
         print(cartItems);    
       });
    }
  });    
 return cartItems;
}
```

and before returning `cartItems` fetch `cartItems` from `_fetchDocumentData` like this

```
cartItems = await _fetchDocumentData();
```

**Explaination:**
Your loop is async and so the values are returned prior to completion of loop's execution.

**Edit:** As you asked here is the code changes that you might want to make.

**Change this:**

```
Future<List<CartItem>> getCartItems() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

  final uid = user.uid;
  List<CartItem> cartItems = [];

  QuerySnapshot data = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("carts")
      .where('owner', isEqualTo: uid)
      .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
      .getDocuments();

  data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    var keys =  doc["products"].keys.toList();
    var values =  doc["products"].values.toList();
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
       await Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(keys[i]).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
        cartItems.add( new CartItem.fromDocument(ds, values[i]));
        print(cartItems);
       });
    }
  });
  return cartItems;
 }
```

**To this:**

```
Future<List<CartItem>> getCartItems() async {
final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

final uid = user.uid;
List<CartItem> cartItems = [];

QuerySnapshot data = await Firestore.instance
    .collection("carts")
    .where('owner', isEqualTo: uid)
    .where('active', isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments();

cartItems = await _fetchDocumentData();
return cartItems;
 }

Future<List<CartItem>> _fetchDocumentData async {
    List<CartItem> cartItems = [];
    data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var keys =  doc["products"].keys.toList();
      var values =  doc["products"].values.toList();
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        await Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(keys[i]).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          cartItems.add( new CartItem.fromDocument(ds, values[i]));
          print(cartItems);
        });
      }
    });
  return cartItems;
}
```

Comment: I tried you solution and replaced the children with suitable data from CartItem, but still just a blank screen... Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: I dont see any difference to my getCartItems() method except the missing Querysnapshot in _fetchDocumentData. Or am I missing the point here? Do you want me to replace getCartItems with your fetchDocumentData?

Comment: The key thing I want to point out here is that, may be you are returning the value before the execution of the loop and that is why in console logs you were getting empty list. And as the list is empty the screen remains blank.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Would you explain your suggestion in your answer a little bit more clearly to me? I would like to try it out :)

Comment: Check my edited answer... If this helps don't forget to accept my answer and up-vote..

Comment: I passed data from getCartItem to the _fetchDocumentData() to prevent any errors. Unfortunatly there is still no visible list... Print(snapshot.data) still outputs [ ], and print(snapshot.hasData) true. Sometimes when changing between apps on my debug device the list is visible, but disappears after hot reloading in the ide or interaction in the app.

Comment: You are still using `async` in forEach function of`_fetchDocumentData` and so problem remained the same.. please remove it and try..

Comment: Ok for that I had too remove the await in the for loop too. But still no change... I edited my question again with the output in the console. You are definitly right, that the Futurebuilder is executed before the fetch is completed!!

Comment: No, see my last comment above.

Comment: Well.. can I see your final code ?? And what is the problem that you are facing now ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191804/discussion-between-kalpesh-kundanani-and-martin-seubert).

Comment: Ok I am in the chat!